# Barcodes using TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, barcode, tcpdf

I am new to Laravel and generating pdf with barcodes, i was able to generate the barcodes for the id of each item and store in the db as html, not i am trying to save the barcode to pdf file using tcpdf but the output isn't expected.

that's to save the barcode to the db which works fine:

```
 $products = Product::get();
    foreach ($products as $p) {
        if ($p->barcode == NULL) {
        $generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML();
        $barcode = $generator->getBarcode($p->id, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128);
        $pro = Product::find($p->id);
        $pro->barcode = $barcode;
        $pro->save();
        }
    }
```

and that's how i am viewing the barcode in the browser

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
                            <div class="barcode">
                             {!! html_entity_decode( $p->barcode ) !!} 
                             
                               <p>Id: {{ $p->id }} </p>   
                               <p> {{ $p->name}} </p>
                               </div>
                           
                               
                            @endforeach
```

that's how the barcode stored in the DB

```html
    <div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:92px;height:30px;">
 <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:12px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:28px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:38px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:52px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:62px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:76px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:84px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

and that's how I am trying to save it as pdf

```
// set style for barcode
    PDF::SetMargins(3, 3, 3);

    // remove default header/footer
    PDF::setPrintHeader(false);
    PDF::setPrintFooter(false);

    PDF::setFontSubsetting(true);
    PDF::SetFont('freeserif', '', 12);
    // define barcode style
    $style = array(
        'border' => true,
        'hpadding' => 'auto',
        'vpadding' => 'auto',
        'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
        'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255),
        'text' => true,
        'font' => 'helvetica',
        'fontsize' => 8,
        'stretchtext' => 4
    );

    PDF::SetTitle('Hello World');
    PDF::AddPage();
    
    PDF::Cell(0, 0, $products[0]->name, 0, 1);
    $code = PDF::serializeTCPDFtagParameters($products[0]->barcode);
    PDF::write1DBarcode($code, 'C39', '5', '5', '60', 14, 0.4, $style, 'N');
    PDF::Ln(5);
    PDF::Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');
```

and that's the output I get:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECmsC.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I clearly stated the question, the output isn't what expected, it tries to barcode the actual HTML/CSS code stores in the database instead of rendering the code to a barcode, and clearly stated the code i used/tried.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should save the id in the db just as ID, not as html.
Then you get the ID from the db and generate the barcode in HTML for a page view and or in a PDF.

Comment: How does this help in the end? Does it make a difference to store the barcode once and read it from that generated state, or generate the same barcode again and again? Does this in any way relate to the PDF problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by passing the actual row id to write1DBarcode instead of the html/css code